# Calling the create method on a Rails controller returns ALL rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to invoke the "create" method of my Rails controller to insert a new record.

Calling `http://localhost:3000/books.json` using `HTTP POST` invokes the `books#create` method, and allows me to insert a new book.

This works fine, but the JSON response returns ALL books that exist in the database. It seems like calling `books#create` somehow also invokes `books#index`.

How can I restrict the JSON output of `books#create` to only the *last inserted record* instead of all records?

Comment: can you show the create action code?

Comment: The controller does not even have a create method. It seems to be using Rails' default/built-in method.

Comment: what is there is your controller? and routes

Comment: Showing more code would probably solve this pretty quickly. The default rails after-successful-create is not an 'index' action, but rather a 'show' action.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably calling the route using a GET request.

Try `curl -d '' http://localhost:3000/books.json` to make a POST request

If that doesn't work, then paste the output of `rake routes` and the `BooksController#create` action.

Answer (score 0):

In route you should specify for json request

```
resources :books , :format => 'json'
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating record successfully you can redirect it to show page of that record with id or
you can tweak your index method conditionally means if you pass id to index it will show only that record else show all the available records.